# How to recognize khmer unicode in intervention images?

Tags: php, image, unicode, laravel-5, imagemagick

I'm using Intervention images packages in Laravel to create Khmer Unicode watermark on the images but all those characters isn't recognize with Unicode format

Used defualt code

```
// create Image from file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// write text
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.');

// write text at position
$img->text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', 120, 100);

// use callback to define details
$img->text('ប្រទេសកម្ពុជា', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->file('foo/KhmerUnicodeFont.ttf');
    $font->size(24);
    $font->color('#fdf6e3');
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('top');
    $font->angle(45);
});

// draw transparent text
$img->text('foo', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
});
```

I got unrecognize format as the images.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest you to use the font that be able to render in different design tool such as for Photoshop, mostly the font start with **Kh**

- [Font support design](https://github.com/osify/cambodianfonts/tree/master/Unicode/Compartible-with-Photoshop-CS3)
- [Font that may work for different hard render](https://github.com/Seuksa/iTextKhmer/blob/master/src/main/resources/kh_battambang.ttf)

Comment: Let I try with those font tonight,

Comment: Dear OSify,
I have try with those font but it still the same
this is the clip you can see that https://youtu.be/dT-NBmmsmz8

Comment: It simply those font is not support with utf-8?

Comment: The GD php library seem not be able to render Khmer text while creating the image, I just tested on my PHP 5.6, can you try out php 7 or something?

Comment: Dear Osify,
I did not use GD to render the images I'm using ImageMagick version 7 on php version 7.1 or 7.0.9 And i also tested with your font and another fonts source even I download from Googles font but still the same now I'm trying to search some tutorials and asking from PHP forum. Some of them said the problem is font.