# PHP Image watermark not support Khmer font Unicode

Tags: php, laravel, image, watermark, intervention

I'm using https://github.com/Intervention/image in my `laravel` Project to generate a watermark on the image. I download and use fonts from https://fonts.google.com and https://github.com/osify/cambodianfonts/tree/master/Unicode/Compartible-with-Photoshop-CS3 Both not working.

I wrote code

```php
            $textFont = public_path('Khmer/Khmer-Regular.ttf');
            $template = Image::make($this->disk->path($user->avatar));
            $text = "កម្ពុជា";
            $template->text($text, 190, 600, function ($font) use ($textFont) {
                $font->file($textFont);
                $font->size(30);
                $font->color('#bc1f1f');
                //  $font->align('center');
                $font->valign('top');
                $font->angle(0);
            });
```

#### Missing font result

[Preview Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik7eo.jpg)

So, Please help suggestion any code or solutions.

Note* I also read and follow
[How to recognize khmer unicode in intervention images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864935/how-to-recognize-khmer-unicode-in-intervention-images)

https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/702

But it is also no solution.
and

Comment: Problem of render, not link to font at the point above, for time being, try this font: https://github.com/Seuksa/iTextKhmer/blob/master/src/main/resources/KhmerOSSiemreap.ttf but I think, it would not work well, if you have the example code of what you do some where, I might try.

Comment: Any PHP code generates Khmer Unicode to png image I can accept

Answer (score 0):

I also try with KH-font but it is not working.
My Solution:

1. NodeJS ([text2png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text2png)) to create image from Khmer Unicode.

```js
const express = require('express');
const text2png = require('text2png');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.get('/image', function (req, res) {
    const buffer = text2png('ប្រទេសកម្ពុជា',
        {
            color: 'red',
            font: '80px Bokor',
            localFontPath: path.join(__dirname, '/../public/fonts/Kh-Bokor.ttf'),
            localFontName: 'Bokor',
            output: 'buffer'
        });

    return res.status(200).send(buffer)
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Express run on port: 3000");
})
```

2. Send request from PHP and combine two images

```js
$data = Http::get('http://localhost:3000/image');

$body = $data->body();

$watermark = Image::make($body);

$image = Image::make(public_path() . "/images/cam.jpg");
$image->insert($watermark, 'center');
$image->save('image.png');
```

[Here is Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMH50.jpg)

Comment: I use your solution easy then java-service. Thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

I really want to use the only PHP.

If I use java working well with code below.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("image")
public class ImageGenerateController {
    final static  String UPLOAD = "";

    @PostMapping(value = "/generate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> generate(@Valid @RequestBody ImagePayload request) throws Exception {

        ByteBuffer buffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(request.getTitle());

        String utf8EncodedString = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString();
        try {
            BufferedImage img = stringToBufferedImage(utf8EncodedString);
            System.out.println(img);
            File file = new File(UPLOAD + request.getName() + ".png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
            String mmm = "ពិតជាអស្ចារ្យណាស់";
            return ResponseEntity.ok(mmm);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Missing something");

    }

    public BufferedImage stringToBufferedImage(String value) {
        //First, we have to calculate the string's width and height

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();

        //Set the font to be used when drawing the string
        Font f = new Font("Khmer OS", Font.PLAIN, 48);
        g.setFont(f);

        //Get the string visual bounds
        AttributedString attributedText = new AttributedString(value);
        attributedText.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, f);
        attributedText.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.GREEN);

        FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontMetrics().getFontRenderContext();
        Rectangle2D rect = f.getStringBounds(value, frc);
        //Release resources
        g.dispose();

        //Then, we have to draw the string on the final image

        //Create a new image where to print the character
        img = new BufferedImage((int) Math.ceil(rect.getWidth()), (int) Math.ceil(rect.getHeight()), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        //Otherwise the text would be white
        g.setFont(f);

        //Calculate x and y for that string
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        int x = 0;
        int y = fm.getAscent(); //getAscent() = baseline
        g.drawString(attributedText.getIterator(), x, y);

        //Release resources
        g.dispose();

        //Return the image
        return img;
    }
}
```